# C# how can I store my integer and do math with it if it's too large for Int32

Tags: c#, math

I'm converting a number specifically

> 2293128329

to Int32 in this line of code here:

```
int nid = Convert.ToInt32(itemId);
```

and its returning  this error

[image: picture_of_error]

Now I know that the number is too big for Int32 as the maximum is `2,147,483,647`  and my number is `2,293,128,329`. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions for how I can fix this issue and continue to do math with it?

Comment: What about converting to int.64, You need a long rather than int.

Comment: `long nid = 2293128329L;` if  `itemId` is of type `string` you can parse it: `long nid = long.Parse(itemId);`. Finally, you can try converting: `long nid = Convert.ToInt64(itemId);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
long nid = Convert.ToInt64(itemId);
```

The number that you deal with overflows Int32 range. But you can use long (or Int64, it's the same thing) and continue doing your math calculations.

Comment: fixed my issue, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use long instead of int or you can use BigInteger (known from Java): https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=biginteger

Answer (score -3):

the problem is that your number is greater than a Int32 could store.

you must use `Int64`. and use `Int64` instead of `int`

```
Int64 nid = Convert.ToInt64(itemId);
```

note that `Int64` and `long` is the same.

Another option is to use an `unsigned Int32`. then the Int32 will not store negative numbers, and then have enough space to store biggers numbers

Comment: There is already an identical answer by @Andrei. No need to explain something so simple twice.